# Checking for string occurrences in a line

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a line of `String` in java, like the following
**deep daap daap peek is 4000**
Is there any way I can check for the occurences of String literals in the line , like a check for patterns like **deep daap**  or    **daap peek**

Comment: ex: "Hello World".contains("Hello");  returns true if the string contains given character sequence

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?(?:\bdeep daap\b)|(?:\bdaap peek\b).*$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/14

Comment: Can you please explain the logic , I didn't get how it is working

Comment: @dileepVikram it simply searches for the string `deep daap` or `daap peek` in the given string.If it finds it,its a pass else fail

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways for you to check:

**Non-regex way** using `contains` (if you are not searching for whole words):

```
String str = "deep daap daap peek is 4000";
System.out.println("Contains: " + (str.contains("deep") && str.contains("daap")));
```

**A regex way** (if you *are* searching for whole words)

```
String rx = "^(?=.*\\bdeep\\b)(?=.*\\bdaap\\b)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Regex: true");
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/138dON)

The whole word presence is checked with 2 anchored look-aheads `(?=.*\\bdeep\\b)(?=.*\\bdaap\\b)`: each checks if there is a whole word (due to `\b`) after an arbitrary number of characters (add `(?s)` at the pattern beginning if you have newline symbols in your input). The check is done right at the start of the string. The regex *requires both* the words to be present.

Comment: Printing `Contains: true` wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @M.Shaw: It is a demo only :) I hardly remember me printing boolean values.